# Eclipse OutOfMemoryError Flex 3

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, flex3

I can only code one line of code, and build. The next change will make an out of memory in eclipse (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError). I am running eclipse through a shortcut with params:
 -vmargs -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:PermSize=128M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M.

I know this question has been done many times but I was wondering if by separating the code into swc libs I will fix this problem. I think I have tried all that is on the net unsuccesfully. My project is just too big! How does the build operation work with libs, does it compile unchanged libs. Will this work? I also want to try this approach because the build takes to long. Does anyone know a good documentation where I can understand what does the build do?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it will not compile the unchanged libraries unless you hit clean the project. I dont think there is a documentation for the same, I've used eclipse.ini file to change the vm arguments, this seems to have worked well for me. try to use this.

If you still need to speed up the compilation speed, i've hacked it previously in the following manner

- Remove all the dependencies of the libraries from the main project. (So, each project builds without disturbing others)
- In the build path of the library project, (output text field) point it to
  the lib location of the main project.
- Under build path > libraries tab add the swc files here and attach source to the lib project

When you build the main project now, it does not take a lot of time as it does not know about the lib projects.

Hope it helps.